# mysql- join multiple table depending on column

Tags: mysql, sql

Maybe this question is duplicate. here situation is different that's why I put the question..

from table m_groups and m_group_admin

```
select m_groups.GROUP_CREATOR_ID as GROUP_ADMIN 
from m_groups where m_groups.GROUP_ID='6'  
union
select m_group_admin.GROUP_ADMIN from m_group_admin 
where m_group_admin .GROUP_ID='6';
```

above query returns a column like

```
| GROUP_ADMIN |
---------------
     4
     8
     2
```

I need user id, first name, last name (m_user_info.USER_ID, m_user_info.FIRST_NAME, m_user_info.LAST_NAME) from table m_user_info for the above outputs

I need output like this

```
  | USER_ID |     |FIRST_NAME|       |LAST_NAME |
  -----------     -------------      ------------
     4             ferdous               wahid
     8             sumon                 sumon
     2             rahul                 paul
```

Comment: If you can show us sample data in those tables, I hope we could optimize the query for better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT USER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
FROM m_user_info
WHERE USER_ID IN 
(select m_groups.GROUP_CREATOR_ID as GROUP_ADMIN 
from m_groups where m_groups.GROUP_ID='6'  
union
select m_group_admin.GROUP_ADMIN from m_group_admin 
where m_group_admin .GROUP_ID='6';)
```

**Explanation:**

It will select USER_ID,FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME from users table with the ids you have got.

Comment: thanks sir @Raging Bull ....it's working. my mistakes is i use =     you use IN. thanks again.....